# Python flask Resources

Tags: flask

Good day everyone, please I just started using flask for web development can anyone recommend books or courses that will aid my journey in becoming a proficient web developer with flask?

Comment: I'm fond of Anthony's tutorials from PrettyPrint.  Try this 40 minute quickstart tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnJKHVEzHFw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find several resources on the internet itself which includes:

- walkthrough tutorials/lectures -- that are either free on platforms like `youtube` or paid-ones like that on `udemy`, `udacity` and others.
- blog posts: Providing a detailed overview of the fundamentals and to complement the same, do a project for the same.
- Flask Documentation itself: Since the best resource to consult would be the documentation itself.

Now, that it is clear that you're starting out. It is highly likely that a walk-through tutorial will be an ideal choice to start with. Among free ones, I'd personally recommend:
**Cory Schafer** on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH) as a starting point. You're however free to choose any paid versions (that usually have a milestone project as well to make sure you have hands-on with what you're learning, but not cramming and cluttering your mind).

Comment: Thanks man, I am now quite proficient in the area.